# How to fix prohibitory symbol on startup?

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, disk-utility, partition, ssd

I have a Macbook Pro Mid 2012 with an SSD installed. The laptop was running a version of OS X 10.13 (High Sierra). The computer froze while I was working on it and I was forced to do a hard reset using the power button.

**Issue**: Prohibitory symbol on startup.

- Can't start up in single-user or safe mode
- Unable to verify or repair containers. Disk Utility presents space manager is an invalid error.
- Unable to verify or repair disk. Disk Utility presents an EFI partition error.
- Unable to reinstall OS X through any type of recovery.
- fsck apfs doesn't work, returns the same errors as Disk Utility.

**My Solution**: Transfer data from corrupt drive to the new drive.

- Replaced SATA cable
- Followed user Klanomath's instructions from similar posts to fix the EFI issue. (Space manager error still present)
- Clean install of OS X on a brand new SSD
- Booted the new SSD from an external as a startup disk
- Installed Catalina on the corrupted drive using an external startup.
- I transferred most of my important files from the corrupted drive to the external drive.

If I attempt to swap the drives around the corrupt SSD becomes unreadable when placed in an external enclosure.

I feel like I've exhausted my attempts to determine what is wrong based on my experience and knowledge. I assume the drive is kaput but I was hoping to try to redeem what I have as there were some files I was unable to access (notes, system files, etc.)

Comment: How old (and worn out) is the SSD?

Comment: @klanomath It's just under 2 years. Aside from me using the computer for design there shouldn't have been enough activity to wear it out.

Comment: @klanomath It appears there was a corrupt data chunk on the drive that was reading an incorrect number of blocks. It was beyond my abilities to figure out so I eventually gave up. I had no issues reformatting the entire drive with a clean install of OS.